# Trying to set a trigger

Tags: css, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'm working on creating my own workout sheet to run on my mobile device b/c I don't like anything the app store offers.

Anyways, I want the sheet to automatically increase the weight being lifted based on a trigger. I've already got the sheet to return the next amount of weight to be lifted using formulas, now I want a trigger to run when the sheet calculates 25 reps to copy that increased value into the weight cell.

I'm trying to use the onEdit function. It runs without giving back an error, but nothing changes on the sheet.

Here's the code I have:

```
function myFunction() {
  function onEdit(e) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    if ("Data!D15" == "False") {
      sheet.getrange("Sheet1!C4").setValue("Data!E15+0");
    }
    if ("Data!G15" == "0") {
      sheet.getrange("Sheet1!C4").setValue("Data!D15+5");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Simple triggers do not display errors. Review your Stackdriver Logs. To start, your script will never do anything because the string literal `"Data!D15"` is not a code instruction to read a value from a sheet -- it is the literal exact character sequence "Data!D15". Review the basics of working with spreadsheets in Apps Script. Start here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  var sh1 = e.range.getSheet();
  var sh2 = e.source.getSheetByName('Data');
  if(!sh2.getRange('D15').getValue()){sh1.getrange("Sheet1!C4").setValue("Data!E15+0");} 
  if(sh2.getRange('G15').getValue()=="0"){sh1.getrange("Sheet1!C4").setValue("Data!D15+5");} 
}
```